# Get value of a property of child element and use it in pure CSS3?

Tags: css

Is it possible to get a value of a property (in my case of child element of a div) and use it as value of parent's property in pure CSS3 without js?

My case: I have a div, which is displayed with animation on mouse hover using this code:

```
.filter {
    height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.filter:hover {
    height: 100px;
}
```

But I want the "destination" (on-hover) height to be not hard-coded, but taken from scrollHeight property of that div's child (a table) increased by a fixed amount using cacl() function. I need this because the size of this table is different on different pages, and the table itself has a box-shadow property, but I want to use single style for this.

If I use

```
.filter:hover {
    height: auto;
}
```

I have no animation and the shadow of inner table stays hidden.

Here is [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexanderSh/bJdMm/).

Can it be done using pure CSS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it purely using CSS3, transitioning the `max-height` property instead of the `height` property.

Set the `height` to `auto` and `max-height` to `22px` initially and transition the `max-height` to something higher that what you expect your largest table to be, like `1000px`.

```
.filter {
    max-height: 12px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out 0s;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.filter:hover {
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexanderSh/bJdMm/2/

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that bottom shadow of the table stays hidden. Are any ways to display it on hover?

Comment: Oh, if I add {padding-bottom: 10px;} property to .filter, everything works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to use attributes from the html markup in css is with the `content` property.

From [this article](http://nicolasgallagher.com/an-introduction-to-css-pseudo-element-hacks/):

> The `content` property can take string, url(), **`attr()`**, counter() and
>   counters() values. The url() value is used to insert an image. **The
>   attr() function returns as a string the value of the specified
>   attribute for the associated element.** The counter() and counters()
>   functions can be used to display the value of any CSS counters.

```
<a href="http://wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>

 a:after {content: " (" attr(href) ")";}
```

> …would display the value of the href attribute after a link’s content,
>   resulting in the following anchor text for the example above:
>   Wikipedia (http://wikipedia.org).

That being said, I don't think this will help for what you are trying to do.